# jQuery sorting inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table with data and need to make it sortable. After sorting the each row needs to get change in its tr id, input id and name attributes.

Here I have done it only for the `name` attribute. But still when saving the data those lines are not in order if more than 1 sorting is done. Probably I am missing something.

And is there so way to change all those attributes at once?

```
    $( "#languages > tbody" ).sortable({
        items: 'tr',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var result = $('#languages > tbody').sortable('toArray');
            for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                $('#Setting3Value'+i+'Language').attr('name', 'data[Setting][3][value]['+result[i]+'][language]');
            }
            for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                $('#'+i).attr('id', result[i]);
                $('#Setting3Value'+i+'Language').attr('id', 'Setting3Value'+result[i]+'Language');
            }
        }
    });
```

And HTML:

```
<table id="languages">
    <tbody>
                                        <tr id="0">
                        <td><div class="input text"><input type="text" id="Setting3Value0Language" rel="" value="English" name="data[Setting][3][value][0][language]"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="input text"><input type="text" id="Setting3Value0Alias" rel="" value="eng" name="data[Setting][3][value][0][alias]"/></div></td>
                        <td/>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr id="1">
                        <td><div class="input text"><input type="text" id="Setting3Value3Language" rel="" value="French" name="data[Setting][3][value][1][language]"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="input text"><input type="text" id="Setting3Value1Alias" rel="" value="fre" name="data[Setting][3][value][1][alias]"/></div></td>
                        <td/>
                    </tr>
 <!-- and so on ... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also is it possible to set the `id`'s of table rows to `name-1` for ex. ?

**EDIT:** I managed to do what I need by using a temp values for the `id`'s because it was getting pretty messy. I dont think that this is the best solution so sill looking forward. Also each input needs to be listed.

***Here is my update function:***

```
            for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                $('#'+result[i]).attr('id', 'temp-'+i);
                $('#Setting3Value'+result[i]+'Language').attr('id', 'temp-Setting3Value'+i+'Language');
                $('#Setting3Value'+result[i]+'Alias').attr('id', 'temp-Setting3Value'+i+'Alias');
            }

            for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                $('#temp-'+i).attr('id', i);
                $('#temp-Setting3Value'+i+'Language').attr('id', 'Setting3Value'+i+'Language');
                $('#temp-Setting3Value'+i+'Alias').attr('id', 'Setting3Value'+i+'Alias');

                $('#Setting3Value'+i+'Language').attr('name', 'data[Setting][3][value]['+i+'][language]');
                $('#Setting3Value'+i+'Alias').attr('name', 'data[Setting][3][value]['+i+'][alias]');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting HTML elements, have you tried the following 
JQuery plugin http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

I'ved used this conjunction with the JQuery UI sortable. It's a very powerful and useful library to sort your elements by particular attribute(s).

hopeful this helps.

**EDIT:** (to update the tr id on moved of item within the sortable container)

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#languages > tbody").sortable({
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).children("tr").each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("id", $(this).index());
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: nice plugin, probably will be usefull somewhere but here I need the element attributes changed depending on their sort order